Deleting helpful comments on "low quality" questions
I just wanted to share something with the community that annoyed me greatly.
I answered a question in the comments. It has gone through a couple of edits, including another user formatting it with MathJax, but at it's core, it's not the kind of question that's received well here: it's vague, full of unstated assumptions and misunderstandings, and really more of a conversation starter than something that can be addressed definitively with an answer.
My comment answer basically said that the power functions $x^n$, where $n$ is an integer, are not one-to-one when $n$ is even, but they are when $n$ is odd, or that they are one-to-one when considering only $x > 0$. As I expected, this elementary observation caused the asker to respond, and refine their question, specifying that $n$ should be odd. It also caused them to ask about what I think they were actually concerned about: the possibility that $n = \infty$. My next comments (which are still up as of writing) addressed this, causing a short back-and-forth between us. In total, I think the OP learned something.
About five hours later, a moderator came by, deleted my first comment, and posted his own, with the simple instruction:

Please do not answer low quality questions in the comments.

Now, I don't have a great attachment to my initial comment. The OP clearly absorbed its message, having adjusted their question on its basis. The question itself is destined for the junk pile, as I stated before. It won't be of any help to people, long term, and even if it doesn't get deleted, the Community bot will likely delete it for us eventually.
However, this moderator's actions are honestly perplexing. Why? Why take the time to delete a comment like that? Even assuming that it was a suitable answer to the question (which, I would say, it actually wasn't: it was more of a challenge to refine the question), what good does the deletion do?

Does it help purify the repository of Q&A? Not really; the question is still up.
Does it help disseminate more mathematical knowledge into the world? Obviously not.
Does it help encourage the OP to write better questions in future? I highly doubt it. The OP spelled out their sense of attachment to the site, or lack thereof, pretty clearly (well, relatively clearly) in a comment:


My background is that I'm 19 years old and completed only high school yet and I am pursuing a Bachelor's Degree in Data Science which has only begun 2 months ago whilst also learning Web Dev. And I am not a bit sad on the fact that I had no idea about numbers, neither I will be happy if I ever am able to collect "stupid reputations" on forums for math like nerds...

(Emphasis mine)
I can only guess that the moderator deleted this comment purely to keep to some odd interpretation of the rules. I worry that the suggestions found in How to ask a good question have now eclipsed, in importance, any of the other goals of this site. It seems more important than helping people with maths. It seems more important than maintaining a repository of high quality Q&A. I'd really hoped that the rules would be enforced in service of these goals, not in opposition to them.
I don't expect, or even particularly want, the comment to be un-deleted. As I said, it has outlived its usefulness. But, honestly, sometimes the moderation of this site just makes me sad.

It seems that a couple more of my (more helpful) comments were deleted after I wrote this, explaining why $\infty$ is not usually included in the real numbers/integers. All that's left is the last in the series of three comments, which now makes little sense in isolation.

Every moderator here would delete answers-in-comments. The fact that Shaun did this one, doesn't make the complaint in this question reasonable or correct.

For reference: This answer by Xander strictly implying that answers in comments are not allowed was not that well received, however hardmath's answer to the same question received consnsus

(continued)Quoting from it: "In summary I don't think it is desirable to enforce "strict" policing of Comments on low quality Questions when gray area exists between encouraging the OP to edit and improve and suggesting an approach to solving the underlying problem. If the OP is able to rethink their approach and potentially answer an improved Question, everybody wins."

18 upvotes is not bad, but this question is still relatively active, and the top answer there got 92 upvotes and two downvotes. I don't think we have a consensus on this at all.

The content is irrelevant to the substance - your actions were in breach of policy, the breach was rectified, now you're complaining that you got caught out and called out, just like everyone else. My answer already dealt with that, so, why keep harping on an issue that supposedly doesn't and won't matter after Roomba goes around.

@Nij I don't believe there is such a policy, and deleting my comment would not have rectified anything even if there was.

You have been repeatsdly informed of it: do not answer in comments. That you have to go back nearly 14 years to find support for your position otherwise, knowing how significantly policies have changed in that time, on top of the personal involvement here and the frequency you do so, just makes you seem without good faith here. Good luck fighting enforcement if you're not prepared to (get policy) change(d).

@Nij "That you have to go back nearly 14 years to find support for your position otherwise, knowing how significantly policies have changed in that time" OK then, go to the next answerer, from less than a year ago. That page is still very much active.

@D.S. This perplexing fear of "low quality questions" is not really something we should be indulging. The idea that they're coming from people who are carefully reading other people's contributions is... kinda silly. Helping someone who is unable, or even unwilling to write a question to our standards, mostly just means someone got the help they needed. And ideally, after they get such help, we can quietly dispose of the substandard question, and keep the repository pristine.

@TheoBendit well you are entitled to your take, but you do know that a lot of people here seem to see things differently. The extra challenge you are facing on here--besids a difference of opinion  however, is that your preferred posting style of answering in the comments, is not only something people here have their reasons for disagreeing with, but it is also something that goes against the MSE guidelines. And I'm not sure how many of us you are going to convince otherwise.

@Mike I don't see why the onus is on me to disprove that answering in comments is against MSE guidelines. I think it's been well-established by now that there is no community consensus that it's bad, or at least, bad enough to ban. I know you don't care for it, and I take no pleasure in causing you annoyance, but that's not enough cause for there it to be banned. At least 26 people found it to be a better option, in the post EoQS MSE. I don't expect to convince you that it's not that bad, but I would have thought the evidence would cause you to pause when claiming it's against MSE guidelines.

@TheoBendit Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment In particular "When shouldn't I comment" towards the bottom of the page. The proof is right there.

@DS "This answer by Xander strictly implying that answers in comments are not allowed was not that well received..." Regardless of whether or not the answer was well-received, it is a network-wide policy, and is one which we enforce here.  This is a policy which we, as moderators, have chosen not to overrule on a per-site basis, whether or not the community would like us to override it (it is not clear that the community does want an override, but that is kind of moot).

@Mike I think the answer "Comments are not recommended for..." to the question "When shouldn't I comment?" is confusing. "not recommended" is not a prohibition.

@XanderHenderson Thank you for weighing in. I also agree that it's not clear the community does want this overridden. I would just like to point out that, though I don't know a community that does encourage answers in comments, not all of these recommendations are enforced on every site. For example, on Puzzling, compliments in comments seem to be commonplace, and can be found on many of the top-rated posts.

@TheoBendit I'm still not understanding your issue here. You posted a comment that is at least "not recommended" [and that many of us think is bad for the site] and so the comment was deleted. You weren't banned you were merely told to stop with the "not recommended" antics. Are you saying that just because you disagree with the not recommended your comment should have gotten to stay up?
Meanwhile "not recommended" does not mean allowed either. There very well could be site policy  [the whole SE vs just MSE] that actually says don't do that.

What is (currently) clear from votes on the answers is that the community (more precisely, people who cared enough to vote) is evenly divided on the issue.

I have written several times (on Meta Math.SE) about the value of context in preparing Answers.  On the one hand it expedites preparing the Answer by giving those willing to make an effort a good idea of the background level of the one posing the Question.  No sense in writing at length in ways that go over the head of the OP or that merely duplicate matters already well known to them.  On the other hand it helps avoid "pass through" Questions, posts made without essential understanding of the topic, sufficient for the OP to assess correctness of answers well enough to accept a good one.

No @Mike, I have no desire to see the comment again. My question is a bit muddled, but I did mention twice that its use is fulfilled. I'm just despairing about how our moderators are choosing to use their time. Deleting a comment that did no harm, and did the OP some good, on a question that will be deleted, and taking the time to tell me not to do it in future. I just don't see an upside to that action, and it represents something quite worrying that shouldn't be left unchallenged: that following recommendations and enforcing controversial issues are more important than helping people.

I have been asked to comment on this. I agree with the consensus of the answers thus far and so I don't have anything to add.

Thank you for responding @Shaun. I appreciate it. I do want to point out, the consensus of answers thus far (by which I assume you mean every answer but mine?) don't really address the issue. I would like to know, why did you decide to delete that comment in particular, and tell me not to answer in the comments? Was there some harm to this action that I just wasn't seeing? Or was it purely to enforce what you see to be the rules of the site?

Oh, and just about the "consensus of the answers thus far", I would like to point out that, aside from Xander's (still a little controversial) comment, the least controversial answer, by ratio of max(upvotes, downvotes) to total votes, is currently xxxxxxxxx's answer with a mere 57% positive upvotes. There very much does not appear to be a consensus here at all.

@XanderHenderson sorry for bit of a tangent here but if the whole community is more so inclined towards the opposite policy, why not take a proper consensus and enforce the winning vote?. The current one feels a little opposite to the essence of stack exchange where democracy is above all.

I think you are very focused on the -helping others in math-, regardless of whether or not they have some respect for this or that; nevertheless I also don't like at all that your well-intentional math-comment was deleted...  but, at least for this case, maybe your math comment should have not been there, to begin with.

@Scypher_Tzu In general, moderators enforce global SE policy unless there is (a) a good reason to overrule network policy, (b) no harm caused to the site by overruling the policy, and (c) a very clear and unambiguous signal that overruling the policy is what the community wants.  In this case, (a) I don't think that there is a good reason to permit answers in comments (it runs contrary to the intentions of the site), (b) I think it would cause some marginal harm (it makes answers harder to find, since search engines prioritize answers, and (c) there doesn't seem to be such a signal.

This answer is narrowly focused on the policy question raised by the question.  It makes no reference to the specifics of the case or cases cited in the question, and is intended to provide clarity about what the official policy is on Math SE, vis-à-vis comments (and, specifically, answers in the comments).
Comments are Second Class Citizens
Per the Help Center

Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be upvoted (but not downvoted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.
...
When shouldn't I comment?
Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
...
Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
...
Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

Note that the first sentence indicates that comments are temporary.  When you write a comment, you should do so understanding that any comment can be deleted at any time for any reason.  Comments are, at best, second class citizens here.
Note also that the Help Center does outline several specific kinds of comments which should be avoided.  I've highlighted a few of those examples (including using the comments to post answers), as these are the ones which seem to come up most often.  This is a network-wide policy, and the diamond-moderators here have made no move to overrule that network-wide policy.

"When you write a comment, you should do so understanding that any comment can be deleted at any time for any reason." It seems to me that anything we post, be it comment, answer, or question, can be deleted at any time for any reason. Is that not within the powers of the moderators?

@GerryMyerson sure, but other posts are still visible to anyone with enough reputation, and non-moderators can see the record of deletion. Moreover, comments are designed to be deleted, which is not the case with other posts. You should expect comments to be deleted; this is not the case with question and answer posts.

"...other posts are still visible to anyone with enough reputation, and non-moderators can see the record of deletion." Xander, that's only the case if one has had the foresight to take down the URL of a deleted question before it got deleted. Otherwise, unless it was my own question that got deleted, it's as good as gone forever, with no way for me to track it down.

@GerryMyerson In the moderator tools available to people with sufficient reputation, there is a link to "recently deleted posts".  There are also SEDE queries which can find deleted posts.  It is not easy, but it is doable.  But, again, the most salient point is that comments are meant to be deleted.  They are temporary.  When you post a comment, you should do so with the expectation that it will be deleted eventually.

@GerryMyerson I would ask that you please remain civil.  Starting off with "Come off, it Xander" is unnecessarily hostile, and seems to imply that I am commenting in bad faith.  Comments are fundamentally different from questions and answers in many ways.  Certainly, it is within the power of the moderators to delete anything, but the simple fact is that we don't, that deletions of questions and answers are more auditable by non-moderators, and if moderators were unilaterally deleting a large number of posts, there would likely be a much deeper problem.

I really don't believe that this is is a good policy to begin with. If you just declare comments to be subject to removal at any time, it provides a pretty good justification for mods to remove comments willy-nilly and just say "Oh, well, comments are supposed to be ephemeral anyway, so it doesn't matter. (Not referring to any particular scenario here.) I understand the rules for removing comments are a bit more lax than for posts, but that first line still seems problematic given how broad a set of actions it justifies.

Thankfully this kind of deletion doesn't happen too often, but I see nothing stopping moderators from doing it. This policy could be improved if it just stated the reasons for removal.
"When you write a comment, you should do so understanding that any comment can be deleted at any time for any reason" seems similar to "By using our app, you agree to indemnify us from legal action". Doesn't seem to be a fair policy.

@stickynotememo The reasons for removal are outlined in my answer and in the help center:  comments are meant to be temporary notes indicating how a post might be improved.  Comments which don't offer suggestions for improvement or ask for clarification don't meet that standard and will generally be removed.  Comments which do meet that standard, but which have been addressed by edits to the question or answer will generally be removed.

Your problems are right here:

I answered a question in the comments.

and

it's not the kind of question that's received well here: it's vague, full of unstated assumptions and misunderstandings, and really more of a conversation starter than something that can be addressed definitively with an answer.

Everything else in your meta post here is an attempt to back-justify your choice to ignore well-established policies, that you are almost certainly explicitly aware of, given the above quoted statements.
Any moderator is perfectly reasonable in deleting such comments, and should be considered ethically obliged to do so, because that's their role as a moderator. Other users can't willy-nilly delete comments that breach policy; only moderators can, and in this case, one has.
This isn't the first time you've ignored such policies either. If you don't believe they are good policies, change them by consensus here. If you don't want to follow them, change where you are active.

Well, here's the thing Nij: answering in comments has been a long established, not particularly controversial practice here on MSE for a long time. The deletion of answers in comments has been vary rare, though there has been a small uptick in recent years. The other problem is not really my problem, it's the OP's problem, should they want to keep their question here and gain reputation. But, I don't get that impression: I think they just wanted to ask a question and get some knowledge. What I don't see in your answer is a reason for this enforcement, beyond purely for the sake of enforcement.

Answering such questions in comments strikes me as a perfect compromise. They serve both goals of MSE: it educates people, and it doesn't pollute the sites Q&A repository. I just don't see a single positive out of what you suggest.

It might be long established, but it is absolutely false to claim answering in comments is "not particularly controversial" when there is yet another meta Q&A turning to disputes over it every other month, including this one itself as evidence.

I would say there is more of a controversy over comments being deleted, which is a more recent trend. Back in 2011, the consensus was to ask the commenter to answer, and if no response, then post the same content as a community wiki - note the lack of accusation of wrongdoing here. I'm not finding a lot of other posts against answering in comments, and I don't remember any while I was active here on meta. It's only recently I've seen people have anything bad to say about it on MSE.

@TheoBendit the purpose of comments is to request clarification, provide constructive criticism (aimed at improving the post) and to add some relevant or useful information. Since only moderators or posters can delete comments, moderators should delete anything that is not the above. However, I have seen some hint-answers (including mine) remain undeleted if they were aimed at getting the OP to show their efforts.

And, my information about $f(x) = x^n$ being even when $n$ is even, was that irrelevant, or was it useless? Like your hint answers, and just as I intended it, it got the asker to improve their question (removing a trivial exception), and focus more on the true source of their issues: their doubts about $f(x) = x^\infty$.

However, one also notes that "Comments are temporary", and search engines do not pick up on them quite easily, also, I can't see which comment caused what (since you say some have been deleted). The best practice would have been to request clarification as to what exactly the OP is asking (which imo is still not clear, but one can make an educated guess) then answer if the question is improved.

Assuming your comments got the OP to improve their question (the downvotes say otherwise), the comments served their purpose, and ought to be deleted. Note that MathSE is intended to be a repository of high-quality Q/A, not a forum.

@DS Don't assume; check. Before, the question was vague and trivial. After, the question was just vague. Downvotes don't measure improvement.

@DS MathSE, in reality, serves dual purposes. It does, in reality, function both as a forum and as a repository. While sometimes these are in contention, often there's great synergy. Some people have taken to denying one of these purposes, which I think is needlessly reductive.

@TheoBendit trivial -> non-trivial is not an improvement, because trivial depends on who you ask. But (usually), if a question is vague, it is unclear to almost everyone except the OP. MathSE discourages vague questions, not "trivial" ones.

@DS A reasonable point. By trivial, I mean anyone who naively answered would have pointed out something the asker already knew, and they would want to change the question, or ask a new one afterwards. That is, it would court unsatisfying answers. If I were to ask you, in particular, would you agree that removing this kind of triviality is an improvement?

Personally, yes it is an improvement, but what I think of something, or my opinion, does not decide what the rules of this site are.

This thread does read to me a bit like 'well I did something that I know its against the guidelines but why is that guideline actually enforced on me'?
And...it is against the guidelines. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment In particular, "When shouldn't I comment" towards the bottom of the page.
This rule is in place for a reason though. Thing is, it isn't just that one user coming on here and asking a bad question and why can't we just take a moment to help that person anyway. It appears to be A LOT of bad questions--questions that don't meet the MSE Guidelines that is-inundating this site though, and a lot of us think that these types of questions should not be encouraged on here, certainly not with an answer-comment or an online tutoring session. I am one of those people.
It has gotten to the point where I have actually reported answering-in-the-comments for that reason. What's the point of having a rule that many of us think is a good idea if it's not enforced?
The joy of helping someone on here with maths, for one thing, is tempered a bit with the sense that we may actually be giving help on homework--or even an exam--that is not authorized by the instructor. That's not the only thing I have against these types of questions though.
Anyway I don't think this is the first time a question like this has been asked. I remember at least one more thread where someone was upset that their hint-comment got deleted and the general consensus on that thread was that deleting that was the right thing to do. I need to find that thread.

"What's the point of having a rule that many of us think is a good idea if it's not enforced?" So, in your opinion, enforcement of the rule is the highest goal here? We don't need the enforcement to serve any kind of purpose, other than to justify having a rule in the first place?

"The joy of helping someone on here with maths, for one thing, is tempered a bit with the sense that we may actually be giving help on homework--or even an exam--that is not authorized by the instructor." Sure, but surely this is independent of the "rules" being discussed here? There's no reason that a request for cheating cannot be asked well on this site, nor is there any reason for every poor question to be a request for cheating? Certainly, in this case, I don't think the question was a cheating request.

In fact, this is often how I deal with this possibility of academic skulduggery: I prefer to engage with the person in the comments. I would often rather lead them to discover the answer for themselves through comments, if it's possible. This is true regardless of how closely the questions follow the site guidelines.

@TheoBendit I just don't think low-quality questions belong on MSE cheating or not [although that it may be cheating does add to it] and I don't agree with you that MSE should be a sort of online office hours either. Anyway I think comment-answers are bad for the site so I report them.

I see that. Please don't interpret my passion as a lack of appreciation for your considered response. I just see this as an opening to understand a perspective that I've never really understood before. So, could I ask, about the online office hours, could I ask why? I'm not saying you have to engage in them. Why would people getting guidance in the comments be of detriment to this site?

Never mind, @Mike. I found an expanded version of this answer here when replying to Nij. I took from it four points, some of which you touched on here: 1. Comments make proper answers less fun, 2. It's just not how the SE sites are supposed to run, 3. It may cause more "low quality" questions to be posted, and 4. There's a chance that you'll be giving unfair advantage with their assignments.

I would say, with points 3 and 4 in particular, these are inevitable consequences of handing out knowledge. There is always a chance someone will use it to gain advantage or cheat. There is always a chance that others may rush into asking a question, without reading the several pages of FAQs we expect them to read. But, I would like to think, by the virtue of us showing up here at all, that we also appreciate the enormous benefits of handing out information. Showing up here specifically to stymie the flow of information is surely the more egregious perversion of the SE model.

Theo, If you want to answer: Do so in an answer field.  Don't make a mountain out of a mole-hill... when you aren't even open to honest input and answers on policy.

"I would often rather lead them to discover the answer for themselves through comments, if it's possible." --- Ah finally you said it. You are just on the wrong site. This is not how MSE works. You will find more joy in classical discussion forums then.

@MartinBrandenburg For a long time, this was the right site for this. We could actually compromise, and both deliver a repository of the Q&A and actually help the people who came to us, when they came to us. I feel like a relatively small portion of the community simply decided that they wanted to kill off the latter usage of this site (by declaring it dead, or gaslighting us into thinking it never was). I'm not sure if they have the authority to do that, nor do I think that it's a sensible course of action.

As requested by amWhy, at multiple points, let me self-answer.
First, let me acknowledge something: I was arguably in violation of the Enforcement of Quality Standards. This is something that I am on the fence about, for a few reasons:

The guidelines in How to ask a good question are not hard-and-fast. What some people may feel are "good enough" may differ from what others feel are "good enough".

While I agree that the question was not clear, that is what the deleted comment was supposed to achieve. It was a trivial observation that technically answered the question presented, with the principle intention to figure out what source of confusion the asker had. The body of the question seemed to suggest more of a confusion about limits to $\infty$, without making this explicit. This assumption was swiftly validated, as the asker edited the question to make the source of their confusion more explicit, thus improving the question. I have seen many instances of similar actions from users who have vocally supported EoQS, where a technical answer is given, in order to get the asker to clarify their question.

The above point notwithstanding, the two comments that were removed after posting the question, and after the moderator posted his comment, were directly answering the source of confusion. I could not see any evidence that there might be further clarifications that the poster would want to make.

There is also an ambiguity about the term "answering" in the EoQS. To "answer" a question is used both in its usual sense, but also as the term for writing and submitting in the answer box. The policy is not particularly clear on that point, nor is it clear how the people who upvoted it feel. I would like to say, this point is included last, because it is by far the least of the reasons I'm on the fence.


With that out of the way, let me answer my question - this answer, in my opinion, will be the first to do so.
My actions caused little to no harm to MSE, and the good it did far outweighed any negatives.
By helping the OP in the comments, the OP learned something. They learned a bit about $\infty$, and they learned a bit about the limitations of their own knowledge on the topic.
I also counteracted some of the arguable toxicity of another comment, now deleted presumably due to JonathanZ's flag. I showed that us "math like nerds", to borrow the OP's turn of phrase, could be helpful, instead of just abrasive and elitist. I hope it fans the OP's curiosity, rather than crushing it. This is extra important, because the user is very new; this was only their second question, and they had not been a member longer than a fortnight.
According to EoQS announcement,

In addition to making it more difficult to clean up low-quality questions, these kinds of answers reward users for their low-quality contributions, and encourage further low-quality contributions in the future.

By helping in the comments, I do not make the question more difficult to clean up. Answering in the other sense could have: answers with positive scores, as I understand it, prevent the Community bot from auto-deleting negatively-scored questions. This was very much on my mind when I decided to comment: I have no desire whatsoever to pollute the repository of questions we ultimately decide to keep.
The other concern is the future proliferation of "low quality" questions. My approach did little to mitigate this. But, I also don't believe that the concern is particularly warranted, at least in this case. Let's break this down into two possibilities:

The OP will post another question of similar "quality", and/or
Another person will read the OP's post, observe that it received help, and will post their own question of similar "quality".

As I put in a comment on this question, I think the concern about point 2 is largely overblown. Our consistent frustration with users not taking the tour, not reading How to ask a good question, etc, is largely borne out of the fact that they don't tend to read the information thrown at them when posting a question. The idea that they first canvas our recent questions is, as I said, silly.
As for point 1, as I pointed out in the question, the asker does not appear to wish to engage with us again (which I think is a shame). However, I acknowledge that, by helping the OP, there is an elevated chance that they will post another "low quality" question. There's also a reduced chance that they'll re-post the same question later, hoping to get a different response from different people. But, there is a non-zero chance that the OP will get over their umbrage and post more questions of similar "quality".
I also believe that this particular "harm" is not particularly likely, nor is it significantly harmful. It will only take a few such questions before a question ban is triggered. Plus, the OP seemed responsive and a sufficiently competent communicator (in English) to understand what is and is not expected by the site. I would expect them to pick up a deeper understanding about what is expected here as time goes on, should they wish to engage further with the site (again, unfortunately, I have my doubts that this will happen).
So, in summary, despite my best efforts to mitigate it, there is a very small risk of relatively trivial harm. But, on the other hand, more quality knowledge about mathematics is now out in the world.

Theo, I know I'm ignoring the bulk of the points you make here, but can I ask you that the next time you see a toxic comment, flag it, immediately? You're right there in the comments, and I think having a mean response sit there, uncontested, does more damage to a new user's impression of the site than any useful engagement can undo.

@JonathanZ Yeah, I agree, I probably should have flagged that comment. I still believe everything I wrote here with regards to comments, and the comment did have some actual content to it (pointing out the OP had stuff to learn). I dismissed it as borderline, and responded with a softer comment saying the same thing. But, on reflection, you were 100% right to flag it.

@amWhy The questions posed to me, at least the ones I've seen, have been largely rhetorical, and largely not on topic. I have still responded to them, only in comments. I didn't want to respond to them in an answer because that's not really what answers are for. I really don't want to post a new answer for every slightly off-topic challenge or comment, nor do I want to have to maintain an ever-growing list of responses in one "answer". Also, I have no idea why you're accusing me of not listening; I think I had responded to every comment of which I had been notified.

@amWhy I also have a personal policy, especially when debating online, to not take accusations hurled at me very seriously. I think that might be the holes in my responses that you may be noticing. For example, when Nij said "...makes you seem without good faith here", I don't tend to respond to things like that, because the debate isn't really about me, so much as my actions. Nij can think how they like about me, and I have no interest in convincing them that I'm a good person. But, I respect you more, so I thought I'd try to explain it from my perspective.

@Theo - I'm asking you, and everyone else, to reconsider your stance on "the comment did have some actual content to it". I think that's a common attitude in math circles: talent excuses bad behavior. I'll make no comment on its effect IRL, but in on-line communities it's poisonous. I've reached the stage where a comment with a two-line proof of FLT that is unkind is going to get flagged by me, and I wish others would flag more often.

Yep @JonathanZ. Well said. I need to readjust my own thresholds.

@TheoBendit on this post at least you are expressing your opinions as if they are facts on here. I for one disagree with your points on this post. It feels to me that you think it is OK for you to override "answers in the comments are not recommended" because you feel your intentions are good.

@Mike It's not so much that my intentions are good, but that my actions are relatively harmless, and do good in other areas. I'm very open to hear if people see issues in my reasoning here. I'm sorry if I express my opinions as though they are facts. I know that they are not. Some were expressed with some unearned confidence, mostly to counteract Nij's unearned confidence.

You shouldn't be answering any questions using the comment field (the whole point is that answers should be able to be upvoted or downvoted), and you shouldn't be answering low quality questions at all.
Answers left in the comments don't belong there and should be deleted.

So, don't call it "answering". Call it "helping". Is there a reason that "helping" in the comments needs the ability to be down-voted? A bad comment is, and always has been able to be remedied by another comment. Is there a reason to not help people who post "low quality" questions?

@TheoBendit Absolutely. Maybe it is not helping; maybe it is completely incorrect. But it can't be downvoted, there is no way for other users to indicate it is bad information without leaving yet another comment. (Also you seem to acknowledge that your comment already helped the user, and that the question itself will inevitably be deleted taking the comment with it; so why is it a problem if the comment is deleted first?)

Right. There is no way for other users to indicate it is bad information without leaving yet another comment. Well, except for upvoting a different comment that points out the problem. Either way, everyone learns more, including the person who left the bad comment. I'm just not seeing the downside here. (Oh, and there's also flagging the comment too, for the sake of completeness.)

If there was a problem with my comment, it would have been much, much better for someone to have corrected me in another comment. Others who agree could have up-voted that. What I'm complaining about is the enforcement of standards to the point where we actively fight the very purposes of this site.

In many ways, a downvote is far inferior to leaving a comment. Downvotes have become almost like noise; more likely an indication that a person doesn't like you, rather than indicating a problem with the content of an answer. The downvote says "there exists something that someone believes is wrong". As far as declarative statements go, it's kinda worthless.

Regarding "Maybe it is not helping", this is a risk we take whenever we try to help anyone! Does that mean nobody should be trying to help anyone out? If so, then what are we doing here?
